# Traefik: Undefined backend for frontend

Tags: docker, docker-compose, load-balancing, traefik

Facing an issue I can't really solve. New to Traefik and the load balancing world really. I have tried searching on the gh issues but haven't found any conclusive answers. 
https://gitlab.com/snippets/1758196 is my toml file, https://gitlab.com/snippets/1758198 is my compose file.

Also, I know I only have one instance of my node server running, but I'm just trying to test Traefik out first, then scale from there.

I would expect this setup to work but I keep getting:

`level=error msg="undefined backend 'backend-app' for frontend frontend-Host-DOMAIN-0. Skipping frontend frontend-Host-DOMAIN-0..."`

This means that I can't access my node server from port 81 or 444 (traefik basic "404 page not found" plaintext appears). Strangely enough, accessing from domain name instead leads to a time out, even with port forwarding working.

Any point in the right direction would be super helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the following from your compose file.

```
  - traefik.backend=app
```